# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n+k}<3/4.$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

I could easily proved the following:
$$\frac12<\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n+k}<1.$$
But, I am not able to show that the sum is actually less than $3/4.$ May I get a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first inequality, you need $n>1$ and it's direct since you sum positive terms with the first one being $1/2$.
- Hint for the second inequality : $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}.$$

Comment: First of all thank you sir... As far as I've understood, the later expression resembles, for $n\to\infty$, the Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^1 \frac1{1+x}\,dx$ which evaluates to $\ln2\approx 0.69<0.75=3/4.$